# jquery-ui: dragging element outside viewport

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a situation in which I have a menu hidden outside the viewport.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: -100px;
}
```

I also have a draggable element. Now, when I drag the draggable to the right and try to move it outside the viewport (also on the right side), I can make the menu visible by somehow moving the viewport to the left. Checkout the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvJhE/195/)
How can I disable this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Scroll option to prevent the page from scrolling.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({scroll: false });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9HK7S/1/)**

It can be used together with `containment: "parent"` to prevent the box sticking out of its parent.

What seem to be happening with your code is that the page is scrolled when you reach the corner and then never scrolled back as you have `overflow: hidden` set for `body`.

The downside with using `scroll: false` is that you won't be able to drag the element down the page either.

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you wish to keep it in `containment` - eg

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

**[Like this ?](http://jsfiddle.net/KPa6u/)**

---

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

---

**Update :** the demo shows the 'containment' away from the element of body - as @Mathias points out the 'overflow hidden' on the body doesn't mean you can't 'drag' to it. So wrapping in elements away from these solves that.

Comment: I noticed that in your example, you can drag the item still out at the bottom

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri, yeah if you wanted to , then this would allow that

Comment: No, that is not what I want. Is the only way to stop this from happening to set `scroll` to `false` ?

Comment: Think of it like any html element, they grow as content grows - see in this example - jsfiddle.net/3WgnH - the height of the 'containment' is not set, so it can't scroll beyond the 'content'. All depends on what your 'design' is as to wether you need to use `{containment:'parent'}` or `{scroll:false}` or both